# How to send data in little endian order C

Tags: c, endianness

I am communicating with a board that requires I send it 2 signed byte.

explaination of data type
[image]
what I need to send
[image]

Would I need to bitwise manipulation or can I just send 16bit integer as the following?

```
int16_t rc_min_angle = -90; 
int16_t rc_max_angle = 120;

write(fd, &rc_min_angle, 2); 
write(fd, &rc_max_angle, 2);
```

Comment: @CostantinoGrana The manual says "Units: 0,02197265625 degree."  I have no idea what those 2 numbers mean but I think its in degrees?

Comment: 0.02197265625 is 45/2048. The units are 45/2048ths of a degree? Be careful!

Comment: Some compilers have extensions to define variables as either big or little-endian.  This is very useful because some architectures, like powerpc, are able to read/write integers in both modes.

Comment: @JohnKugelman is that comma a typo on the manual?  Period would make more sense.

Comment: It's a European-style decimal point, I presume.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I can't see my original comment anymore. Anyway, I was not too far: it's not radians, but it's fixed point even if I don't get why 45/2048ths of degree instead of a simpler 1/2048ths.

Comment: @bakalolo As John Kugelman said, you have to take your degrees, multiply them by 2048, then divide by 45. So -90 becomes -4096, 120 becomes 5461 and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int16_t` has the correct size but may or may not be the correct endianness. To ensure little endian order use macros such as the ones from [endian.h](https://linux.die.net/man/3/endian):

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <endian.h>

...

uint16_t ec_min_angle_le = htole16(ec_min_angle);
uint16_t ec_max_angle_le = htole16(ec_max_angle);

write(fd, &ec_min_angle_le, 2);
write(fd, &ec_max_angle_le, 2);
```

Here `htole16` stands for "host to little endian 16-bit". It converts from the host machine's native endianness to little endian: if the machine is big endian it swaps the bytes; if it's little endian it's a no-op.

Also note that you have you pass the address of the values to `write()`, not the values themselves. Sadly, we cannot inline the calls and write `write(fd, htole16(ec_min_angle_le), 2)`.

Comment: Disagree with "Sadly, we cannot inline the calls".  Counter example `write(fd, &(uint16_t){htole16(ec_min_angle)}, 2);`

Comment: Similarly, other platforms have hton() and ntoh() functions in their C libraries, to put the byte swapping into the context of network buffer filling/draining https://stackoverflow.com/q/15863775 . "Host to network", and vice versa.

Comment: @vvaltchev By _inline_ the answerer likely meant the sense of "writing the call inline" (in one line), not "expanding the called function inline".

Comment: @user4815162342 I totally agree with you, I just read the text by far too quickly, missing that. I was focused on `htole16()`, while the whole "inline comment" actually was about the interface of `write()`, not `htole16()`. Anyway, it's fun to observe how quickly the discussion went off-topic, with several comments about the "inlining" of the 2nd argument of `write()`, which is totally irrelevant, given the question `:-)`

Comment: @vvaltchev Good point about the off-topicness - usage of `write()` generated a similar discussion under answer as well. Here it's slightly better because inline expression is not _completely_ off-topic, because it affects the ergonomy.

Answer (score 1):

If endian functions are not available, simply write the bytes in little endian order.

Perhaps with a *compound literal*.

```
//         v------------- compound literal ---------------v
write(fd, &(uint8_t[2]){rc_min_angle%256, ec_min_angle/256}, 2);
write(fd, &(uint8_t[2]){rc_max_angle%256, ec_max_angle/256}, 2);
//                      ^-- LS byte ---^  ^-- MS byte ---^
//        &
```

I added the `&` assuming the `write()` is a like [write(2) - Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have it type-generic, you can simply do:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*most optimizers will turn this into `return 1;`*/
_Bool little_endian_eh() { uint16_t x = 1; return *(char *)&x; }

void swap2bytes(void *X) { char *x=X,t; t=x[0]; x[0]=x[1]; x[1]=t; }

int main()
{
    int16_t rc_min_angle = -90; 
    int16_t rc_max_angle = 120;

    //this'll very likely be a noop since most machines
    //are little-endian
    if(!little_endian_eh()){
        swap2bytes(&rc_min_angle);
        swap2bytes(&rc_max_angle);
    }

    //TODO error checking on write calls
    int fd =1;
    write(fd, &rc_min_angle, 2); 
    write(fd, &rc_max_angle, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To send little-endian data, you can just generate the bytes manually:

```
int write_le(int fd, int16_t val) {
    unsigned char val_le[2] = {
      val & 0xff, (uint16_t) val >> 8
    };

    int nwritten = 0, total = 2;
    while (nwritten < total) {
      int n = write(fd, val_le + nwritten, total - nwritten);
      if (n == -1)
        return nwritten > 0 ? nwritten : -1;
      nwritten += n;
    }
    return nwritten;
}
```

A good compiler will recognize that the code does nothing and compile the bit manipulation to no-op on a little-endian platform. (See e.g. gcc generating the same code for the variant [with](https://godbolt.org/z/lc4Czm) and [without](https://godbolt.org/z/OyEFGf) the bit-twiddling.)

Note also that you shouldn't ignore the return value of `write()` - not only can it encounter an error, it can also write less than you gave it to, in which case you must repeat the write.

Comment: OK fair enough.  Yet if code examines the return value of `write(fd, val_le, 2)`, then why not also the return value of `write(fd, val_le + 1, 1);`?  Seems clear enough to just code `return write(fd, val_le, 2);` and let the caller decide on the error handling.

Comment: @chux You're right, examining the second `write()` cannot be avoided. `return write(fd, val_le, 2)` is insufficent because a _valid_ `write()` can return 1, it's simply not an error case.